# How do I give an option to the user to skip the first calculation part and proceed to the second part?(Python 3.X)

Tags: python-3.x

How do you write an if statement (or anything else), that let the user have a choice to do the first calculation or not. For example,

Do you want to do Calculation A? 
If yes then show the calculation A, else skip to Calculation B.

How do you write this in code?

Comment: Thats the core of the `if` statement. You define the `condition`. Implementation is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

The code itself is trivial.  Assuming you have a boolean called
    doA
where it is true if you want to do the first calc, false otherwise, if looks like:

```
if(doA) :
    # do the A calc
else:
    # do the B calc
```

*# rest of code goes here...*

But I assume you are asking something slightly different?

Comment: This actually will help. How do you set up a Boolean? Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

For cleaner code, define each calculation in a separate function. Use `input()` to retrieve the user's input and use `if`/`else` to check the input and determine which function to call.

```
def calcA():
    print("Calculation A")

def calcB():
    print("Calculation B")

inp = input("Enter yes to do Calculation A: ")

calcA() if inp == "yes" else calcB()
```

Comment: Ummm, followup question. How do I define Calculation A?? It's a series of codes lead to calculations. Like is there some symbol to use in the beginning and the end of the calculation A, to let python know??

Comment: Just put the code in the body of the function. It has to be indented, just like the `print`s in my code are. Look up how to define functions in Python for more info. If you don't want to use functions, you can write the code in the if/else block like in eSurfsnake's answer.